# Input form is not responsive in my Nodejs project.Using ejs as a template engine

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I am using ejs as a template in my Nodejs project but the input form shown in the code is not response.I am not able to input text or click any of the buttons.What could be the possible reason and how can I overcome this issue? The page has dynamic content.

```
    <div class="main">
        <div id="newPost">
            <p style="padding: 4px; border: 1px black solid; background-color: #330066; margin-bottom:0px ; margin-top:10px;width: 775px;margin-left: 10px;border-top-right-radius: 20px; border-top-left-radius: 20px; padding-left: 20px;color: white ">Create
                post</p>
            <form class="form-inline" style="margin-top: 20px" action="/admin/add-post" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <textarea placeholder="Enter your post here ..." name="body"></textarea>
                <input type="file" placeholder="Upload The Corresponding File" name="file">
                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg ml-auto" style="color: white ;margin-right:20px">Add
                    Post!</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="newsFeed">
            <% for(let post of posts) {%>
            <% for(let p of post) {%>
            <div id="samplePost">
                <div class="feedHeader" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
                    <div class="row" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 20px">
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="circle">
                                <img class="profile-pic" src="/images/add.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-11">
                            <h5 style="padding-left: 20px">Author Name</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="feedBody" style="padding: 10px">
                    <div>
                        <img src="/images/prof.jpg" class="feedPic">
                        <p style="padding-top:30px ">
                            <%= p.body %>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <% } %>
            <% } %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it would seem that you surely have a little mis aligned code , a improper nesting .. give it a thorough scan